# На samsung galaxy s3 вот такой экран, после создания апк

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На других устройствах всё работает хорошо

Comment: Samsung(и) они такие, все делают по своему

Comment: Ничего нельзя сделать?

Comment: а на s4 и более поздних такая же проблема?